# Running into errors trying to read Text File

Tags: c, function, pointers, data-structures, text-files

Okay so I'm building a program for work to track volume each day and also split the volume up to how much each different location receives. There are 8 lines in the building. The Text file consists of the day's date, the total volume for the building and the volume for each location (PEN).

Im running into two problems right now both are segregated to my readDay function. where result = fscanf(pi->Date, 40, fp);
issues are
1. Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char*'
2. Incompatible pointer types passing 'char[40]' to parameter of type 'FILE*'(aka 'struct_sFILE*')

Can anyone explain to me what these issues mean. Or if you need any more info in order to help me feel free to ask.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct  Day  {
char Date[40];
int Total;
int Pen1;
int Pen2;
int Pen3;
int Pen4;
int Pen5;
int Pen6;
int Pen7;
int Pen8;


};

const char fileName [] = "UPS.txt";

void StartRecord(void);
void printDay(struct Day* pi);
void writeDay(FILE *fp, struct Day *pi);
int readDay(FILE *fp, struct Day *pi);
void readFile(void);
void addDay(void);



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

StartRecord();

int choice;
printf("Enter 1 to read this file or enter 2 to add to it.");
scanf("%d", &choice);
switch (choice) {
    case 1: readFile();
        break;
    default: printf("Not a valid choice\n");
        break;
}
getchar();
getchar();


}

void StartRecord(void)    {

int count;
int i;
struct Day aDay;
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen(fileName, "w");
if (fp != NULL) {
    printf("Enter volume for how many days? ");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("What is today's date? ");
        gets(aDay.Date);
        printf("What was the total volume for the building for the day?");
        scanf("%d", &aDay.Total);
        printf("What was the volume for Pen 1? ");
        scanf("%d", &aDay.Pen1);
        printf("What was the volume for Pen 2? ");
        scanf("%d", &aDay.Pen2);
        printf("What was the volume for Pen 3? ");
        scanf("%d", &aDay.Pen3);
        printf("What was the volume for Pen 4? ");
        scanf("%d", &aDay.Pen4);
        printf("What was the volume for Pen 5? ");
        scanf("%d", &aDay.Pen5);
        printf("What was the volume for Pen 6? ");
        scanf("%d", &aDay.Pen6);
        printf("What was the volume for Pen 7? ");
        scanf("%d", &aDay.Pen7);
        printf("What was the volume for Pen 8? ");
        scanf("%d", &aDay.Pen8);
        getchar();
        writeDay(fp, &aDay);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}else {
    printf("\nError opening file.\n");
}

}

void readFile(void) {
FILE *fp;
struct Day aDay;

fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
if (fp != NULL) {
    while (readDay(fp, &aDay)) {
        printDay(&aDay);
    }
    fclose(fp);
} else  {
    printf("\nError opening File!\n");
}
}

void writeDay(FILE *fp, struct Day *pi) {
fprintf(fp, "%s\n", pi->Date);
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pi->Total);
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pi->Pen1);
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pi->Pen2);
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pi->Pen3);
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pi->Pen4);
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pi->Pen5);
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pi->Pen6);
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pi->Pen7);
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", pi->Pen8);
}

int readDay(FILE *fp, struct Day *pi)  {
int result;

fgetc(fp);    // read the endline
result = fscanf(pi->Date, 40, fp);
if (result == EOF) {
    return 0;
}
fscanf(fp, "%d", &pi->Total);
fscanf(fp, "%d", &pi->Pen1);
return 1;

}

void PrintDay(struct Day *pi)  {
printf("Records for the day of: %s\n", pi->Date);
printf("Total Volume: %d", pi->Total);
printf("Volume for Pen 1: %d", pi->Pen1);
printf("Volume for Pen 2: %d", pi->Pen2);
printf("Volume for Pen 3: %d", pi->Pen3);
printf("Volume for Pen 4: %d", pi->Pen4);
printf("Volume for Pen 5: %d", pi->Pen5);
printf("Volume for Pen 6: %d", pi->Pen6);
printf("Volume for Pen 7: %d", pi->Pen7);
printf("Volume for Pen 8: %d", pi->Pen8);
printf("\n\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one sense, your arguments are the wrong way round. This:

```
fscanf(pi->Date, 40, fp);
```

should be:

```
fscanf(fp, pi->Date, 40);
```

just like you already have it a few lines further down.

In another sense, what you're trying to do is very strange - you can't read anything into a literal integer. You probably want something more like:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", pi->Date);
```

or possibly:

```
fscanf(fp, "%39s", pi->Date);
```

or similar.

Comment: my input for the date is suppose to look like 10/10/1992 for instance. so i figured its an integer but id need to make to pointer a 'char' because of the '/' between each number. @Paul Griffiths

Comment: So i have another problem and thats when i print the data after entering it won't stop printing the data. I'm not sure exactly where to look to figure out how to stop it from printing. @Paul Grittiths.